Migrate or Copy model from one subscription to another - Doc Intelligence project required in each subscription?
Recently went through the process of copying a working model that Im using with my code. Maybe Im not understanding something, but why do I need a project in document intelligence studio with the target subsubscription, eg.  dev -> test.  I only want to create the model once.  In the other areas or subsubscriptions I dont intend on creating any new models via "training" with sample files etc.  I just need to be able to use the doc service api in that environment and have the model (which I created in the beginning) to be available in the same environment.  Does anyone have a link to something that runs through the scenario of moving these resources from one environment to another?
